# Windows 10 search not working without access to Administrator user folder (domain joined)

Tags: windows-10, windows-domain

We got a problem that when we join a windows 10 computer to the domain search is not working for all domain users (even domain admins) until we give them full control to the Administrator user folder. For local users it works without any problems.

It is a windows server 2012 R2 domain. When I log into the system as a domain user search keeps searching, for example when I type in word. This does not have a time limit, it stays on this until you cancel the search. Found out that by giving full control to the Administrator user folder for a user, it works normally after this. After this I only granted access to the admin local folder, this also worked. Further Research showed that granting full control to the admin\appdata\local\microsoft folder only also fixed the issue. So it is in the microsoft folder that other users require access to.

In event viewer I see the following during the issue:

> In de machtigingsinstellingen toepassingsspecifiek wordt de machtiging Activeren niet verleend aan Lokaal voor de COM-servertoepassing met CLSID {6B3B8D23-FA8D-40B9-8DBD-B950333E2C52} en APPID {4839DDB7-58C2-48F5-8283-E1D1807D0D7D} aan de gebruiker NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE SID (S-1-5-19) met het adres LocalHost (via LRPC) die wordt uitgevoerd in de toepassingscontainer Niet beschikbaar SID (Niet beschikbaar). Deze beveiligingsmachtiging kan worden gewijzigd met het beheerprogramma van Component Services

English Translation from Localized Error Message Lookup:

> The permission settings %1 do not grant %2 %3 permission for the COM Server application with CLSID %n%4%n and APPID %n%5%n to the user %6\%7 SID (%8) from address %9 running in the application container %10 SID (%11). This security permission can be modified using the Component Services administrative tool.\r\n

Comment: Please give more info about the domain : Server Windows version etc. and also about the errors you are getting.